# Block masking URL from nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, unicorn, mask

Some bad person is masking my website with his domain www.baddomain.com. I would like to block it somehow from my `nginx` config file if that is possible.

I tried to see from "baddomain.com" source code if he is using URL frame, but can't find one. Also domain extensions are being duplicated on every page.

I have filled Copyright Claim with his domain issuer but that could be long process or useless.

I own "original.com" but he owns "baddomain.com". I don't want google to think there is duplicate content with my site.

How could I block masking url from Ninx? I use DigitalOcean droplet, Ruby on Rails. Unicorn and Nginx for server!

Comment: How do you think this might be done? What have you tried thus far? Server fault isn't a free consulting service. We have an expectation that you try and resolve the issue on your own first before coming here.

Comment: I tried to block all "frames" from different Q&A here. None worked. When I saw "baddomain.com" source code I can't see that URL frame is used, it starts with regular <html>. Also I have filed many Copyright claims on all institutions I could find. Asking here is last hope, not first! @EEAA

Comment: I think you should [post the real URLs](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632). With these, someone may be able to determine what is going on. Without them, you would have to do so yourself, but you seem to not have the ability or knowledge to do so (which is why you're here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the other domain name has the same IP address as yours. Since the last update to their DNS was in July of 2015, it appears that they simply have a defunct domain, and were the previous user of that IP address.

This is easy to resolve:

It appears that you've placed the configuration for your web site in the nginx default virtual host. This is not a recommended configuration.

Your web site should have its own `server` block, and the default `server` block shipped with nginx should be left unchanged.

To resolve the problem, restore the default `server` block to what was shipped with nginx, and place the configuration for your web site in a separate `server` block. In this way, accesses to any other domain directed at your IP address will be served the default nginx error page.

Comment: And I thought someone is trying to hurt my SEO :D I will update if it worked! @MichaelHampton

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I tried to figure this out for all day. At least 7 hours! Now it displays error page from nginx. @MichaelHampton

Comment: One thing I _do not_ recommend is trying to redirect from the other site to yours. This may make search engines think that you own or control the other domain, which you don't. For SEO, you don't want it associated to you at all. So displaying an error page is the best thing to do.